# R- How to add parts of a column to another column in a dataframe?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, replace

I have a very specific problem. My dataframe looks like this:

[image]

My problem is the Date and Day columns. Currently its like this:

Year-month-1  - And then in the next column the day.

I want it look like a normal Date-Column, like Year-month-day. So I want to take the days out of the 2nd column and replace them with the 01 in the first column.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Try `paste0(substr("1992-06-01", 1, 8), substr("Day21", 4, 5))`. Then change the strings in this by the appropriate columns of your df. Also, images are **not** the proper way of posting data, `dput(data)` is.

Comment: Something like newdate <-  paste0(gsub("([^-]*)$", "",df$Date), gsub("[A-z]+", "", df$Day))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% unite(new_Date, Date, Day, sep = ' ') %>% mutate(new_Date = ymd(gsub("([0-9]{2} Day)", "", new_Date)))
```

This uses tidyr::unite and lubridate::ymd along with dplyr functions.

Comment: This worked for me! Although I could not really fully understand the command! Thx!

Comment: So dplyr works with chains, i.e. the `%>%` operator. In this case, the command uses `tidyr::unite` to combine the Date and Day columns with a whitespace separator and creates a new column called new_Date. Then we apply some regex using `gsub` to convert the new column which will look something like `1992-06-01 Day21` to `1992-06-21`. We do this by essentially replace the `01 Day` part with an empty string. Finally this is converted to a date using the `lubridate::ymd` function. I would recommend investing some time in learning dplyr

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `dplyr` `rear` and `lubridate` packages.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(paste(year(Date), month(Date), parse_number(Day), sep = '-')))
```

The `parse_number(Day)` function gets the numeric values from the `Day` column. The `year(Date)` get the year from `Date` and `month(Date)` get the month from `Date`.

Then the `paste` combines the year-month-day with a hyphen as the separator `sep = '-'`. `ymd` converts it to a date format. `mutate(Date` inserts the new values into the `Date` column.

Comment: So I dont have to cut out the numerics in the Day column? Because I have everywhere Day23 or something like that. The 23 will be extracted by itself?

Comment: @Essi The days from the `Date` column will replace values in the `Day` column.

Comment: I tried it now, when I do that, my Day column only has 1 in each row and the Date column didnt change at all. :/

Comment: @Essi But you asked to replace the `Day` column with the days of the `Date` column. From the picture of your dataframe, your `Date` column only has 1 as the day. So the `Day` will become 1. If your `Date` was '1992-06-30` then the `Day` will have a value of 30.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now. My question was maybe to understand in 2 ways. What I mean is, to take the numbers of the "Day" column and replace the "01" of the Date column with these numbers in order to have a normal date column.

Comment: @Essi Sorry about the confusion. I updated the answer with explanations.